# How to retrieve regional settings from a Windows registry on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, partition, registrykey

I would need to know how to retrieve regional settings from the Windows registry, from a Windows (7 or 10) partition mounted on a Linux system. Please, note that I cannot use Windows directly.

The best would be to to display them directly into the terminal, but I guess it will not be as easy as using `cat registry_file | grep key`.

I am mainly interested in registry keys such as `sCountry`, `Locale`, `LocaleName` and `sLanguage` (but there could be more I am not aware of, since I am more a Linux person). As far as I could see, these keys are scattered system-wide or in each user directory for different purposes but I could not find a final answer on how to read these keys, especially for one user in particular.

Is it possible to achieve that in this situation?

My question is not a duplicate ; I already looked at:

- [Editing Windows registry, from Python, Under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666690/editing-windows-registry-from-python-under-linux) - it does not provide useful information (outdated and/or irrelevant information, broken links, etc.).
- [How to find world region or country or language from the windows registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778981/how-to-find-world-region-or-country-or-language-from-the-windows-registry?noredirect=1&lq=1) - it does not cover the use case of doing it from a Linux system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing Windows registry, from Python, Under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666690/editing-windows-registry-from-python-under-linux)

Comment: My question differs because I do not really where are these keys, how they can interact or override themselves (in order to determine which ones I am really interested in). Hence my question, but it may be too broad.

Comment: Find which ones you care about from inside Windows with plain ol' `regedit`, then use the paths you find in Linux.

Comment: I cannot do it from Windows directly. Moreover, apart from `locale` (which I am not already so sure about), I do not know where to find the others.

Comment: @JosephSible I check the possible duplicate you were refering to. It is outdated: it covers all windows up to 7 only, all but one project quoted in it are not there anymore and documents seems sort of outdated as well, even if I just browsed them.

Answer (score 3):

### Locale Registries

The desired system locales are stored at:

`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\sCountry`

`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\Locale`

`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\sLanguage`

The `sCountry` is only used for the notation format, you could also use the Locale info and link it to this table:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

Additionally, you could take a look on the following registry:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Geo\Nation`

Which stands for the current location as in the following table:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

---

### Registries Location on Filesystem

From grawity's answer on:
https://superuser.com/a/289963

> - Registry: **`HKLM\SYSTEM`**
>
>   File: `\WINDOWS\system32\config\system`
>
>   - Registry: **`HKLM\SOFTWARE`**
>
>   File: `\WINDOWS\system32\config\software`
>
>   - Registry: **`HKU\<user-SID>`** (aka
>       **`HKCU`**)
>
>   File: `<home>\NTUSER.DAT`
>
>   - Registry: **`HKU\<user-SID>_Classes`** (aka
>       **`HKCU\Software\Classes`**)
>
>   File: `<home>\Local Settings\Application
>     Data\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat`
>
>   File:
>     `<home>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\usrclass.dat`
>     – as of Windows Vista
>
>   - Registry: **`HKU\.DEFAULT`** (the system account)
>
>   File: `\WINDOWS\system32\config\default`
>
> Note that `HKU\.DEFAULT` is the **system** account. It is not the
>   template account.
>
> The template account's files are at `\Documents and Settings\Default
>   User` (substitute for `<home>` above).

---

### Editing tools

- `hivex`:

  > This program provides a simple shell for navigating Windows Registry 'hive' files. It uses the hivex library for access to these binary files. https://linux.die.net/man/1/hivexsh
- `chntpw`:

  > chntpw is a utility to view some information and reset user passwords in a Windows NT/2000 SAM userdatabase file (...). In addition it contains a simple registry editor and  a hex-editor with which the information contained in a registry file can be browsed and modified.
  >   http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/chntpw.8.html

---

Additional references:

[How to find world region (or country) or language from the windows registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778981/how-to-find-world-region-or-country-or-language-from-the-windows-registry)
https://superuser.com/questions/289955/access-windows-registry-from-ubuntu/289963#289963
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214856/how-can-i-access-the-windows-registry-from-linux